# Updating a @OneToMany Collection

Tags: jakarta-ee, mapping, ejb, one-to-many

I'm trying to do something like Facebook's wall but I've got a problem.

My DB is made by just two tables, one for the users and one for the posts.
Each post has a reference to the user (a foreign key to the user table).

I've tried to make it work and it goes quite fine, each user can insert his own posts and see the one made by the others, but the insert feature isn't working like it should!

When I insert a new post, it's inserted correctly into the database, but it simply won't show until the next server restart !
It seems that the mapped collection of posts isn't correctly updated, so the bean will return the one that he found at the first run.

Here's the code used to map the entities :

USER

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id    
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "regDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date regDate;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "birthDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthDate;
@Size(max = 255)
@Column(name = "avatar")
private String avatar;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="utente", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Post> posts;
```

POST

```
public class Post implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id = 0;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
@Column(name = "text")
private String text;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "time")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date time;
@JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "username")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private User user;
```

How can I fix that ?

EDIT :

Here's the Managed Bean that works with the posts. It's called by a JSF page that uses getPosts() to fill a dataTable and a form to insert the post (postText is another property that has getter and setter)

```
@Named(value = "postsMB")
@RequestScoped
public class PostsMB {

@EJB
private UtenteFacadeLocal userFacade;
@EJB
private PostManagerLocal postManager;
protected String username;

/** Creates a new instance of PostsMB */
public PostsMB() {
}
protected List<Post> posts;

/**
 * Get the value of posts
 *
 * @return the value of posts
 */
public List<Post> getPosts() {
    //Let's see if we are trying to display posts from another user (passed with a GET param) or from the logged in user
    username = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("username");
    if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
        user = userFacade.find(username);
    }
    if (user == null) {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        user = (Utente) session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //Once we've got the right user, we get all his posts
    posts = new LinkedList<Post>(user.getPosts());        
    return posts;
}
public void insertPost() {
    //We get the user from the session and we use it to insert the post
    user = (Utente) ((HttpSession) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false))).getAttribute("user");
    postManager.insertPost(postText, user);
}
```

This managed Bean calls another Bean (PostManager) that simply calls an auto-generated PostFacade class which inserts the data into the DB.

```
@Stateless
public class PostManager implements PostManagerLocal {

@EJB
private PostFacadeLocal postFacade;

@Override
public void insertPost(Post post) {
    postFacade.create(post);        
}

@Override
public void insertPost(String text, User user) {
    Post p = new Post();
    p.setText(text);
    p.setUser(user);
    p.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    p.setTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    insertPost(p);
}
```

Posts are retrived with this code in User class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Post> posts;

public Collection<Post> getPosts() {        
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(Collection<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}
```

EDIT 2 :

Here's my login method

```
User u = userManager.doLogin(username, password);
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("username", u.getUsername());
```

and here's my getPosts() method of the Posts Managed Bean

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        user = utenteFacade.find(session.getAttribute("username));   
posts = new LinkedList<Post>(user.getPosts());
```

It should do exactly what I've said before, so I store the username(plain String) into a session and then I call the facade's find method to get a new instance of the user.
What's wrong?

EDIT 3:

UtenteFacade

```
@Stateless
public class UtenteFacade extends AbstractFacade<Utente> implements UtenteFacadeLocal {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "LoginSession-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public UtenteFacade() {
    super(Utente.class);
}
```

}

AbstractFacade

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Show use the code used to create the posts and read them, and tell us when you start and commit transactions.

Comment: One hint, try NOT to use your native language in code. This will always bite you later. For instance, when asking for help on a site like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the user's post, you get the user from the session. So, obviously, if some posts have been added or removed since you stored the user in the session, you won't see them.

Don't cache the user in the session, and everything will be fine. If the user must be cached somewhere, it's in the Hibernate second-level cache.

Comment: Right, but isn't the method getPosts() getting them from the database everytime that I call it?

Comment: No. Once the session used to load the user has been closed (usually at the end of the transaction), user becomes a detached object, a POJO. Even if it stayed attached, once the collection of posts is loaded, it's not reloaded anymore from the database. If it did, every method call on an entity would trigger a select query, and the performance would be abysmal. You should definitely read the hibernate reference doc, because you haven't understood very important principles.

Comment: Are you talking about the Persistence Context?

Comment: Sorry. I'm using Hibernate vocabulary. Replace "session" with "EntityManager". in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you answer.
Just to have everything clear..
If I store the username (a plain String) in the HttpSession and I call userFacade.find(username) to get everytime a new instance of the User, will it work ?

Comment: Yes it will. That's what you should do.

Comment: Added few lines of code which should do what I said before, but it just won't work :\ I'm sorry if I'm bothering you

Comment: *it won't work* is not sufficient to help you. What does it do? Any exception? what's the stack trace?

Comment: It works as before. so It adds the post to the db but it won't show it until the nex server restart. I'm not saving the User in the session anymore, so getting a new User instance and calling getPosts() after it has been inserted into db should give me the updated list but it doesn't

Comment: Why do you store the posts in the managed bean? What's the code of the UtenteFacade? Have you debugged your code and tried to see if this facade was called when you expected it to be called (i.e. at each request)?

Comment: UtenteFacade is auto-generated by Netbeans and it just calls the EntityManager's methods.
The managed bean is request scoped, so the EJB Container is generating a new instance on each request..
That's what I don't understand..None of my object is keeping a state from a previous call, I make new instances everytime that I need them but the data seems to be cached somewhere !

Comment: If it's cached somewhere, it must be in the entityManager's cache. Seeing the code of the facade, and kowing the way JPA is configured would help.

Comment: Added code above.
Funny thing is that changing cache mode to None in persistence.xml file made it work, but just for a while..Now it isn't working anymore

Comment: Ok, your answer pointed me out to the solution !
I've added a refresh method that gives me back a managed User everytime that I need it !
Thanks again :)